# Does stack overflow have a forum?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, site-recommendation

I really like this site for reference and the experience of others. I think it would be nice to be able to ask questions that require experience and a sprinkle of opinion.

For example, the other day I asked what are the advantages of using Haskell programming over C++ and what were developers thoughts on Haskell. Immediately I was down-voted and told by multiple people (like one wasn't enough) that I cannot ask this because it is not a direct answer and was too open for opinion. I asked simply because I was curious about learning a new development language and wanted to know other developer's shortcomings and advantages of the language.

If there is not a forum for this would the development team take thoughts into creating one for questions that do not meet the criteria for questions on this site. I particularly like having experienced developers give insight from their experience. Pardon this question if it does not meet the criteria of what is allowed to be asked.

Answer (score 7):

Not exactly... But they do have [a third place](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/do-trilogy-sites-need-a-third-place/): Chat!

- https://chat.stackoverflow.com/ (for Stack Overflow)
- https://chat.stackexchange.com/ (for all Stack Exchange sites except Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange)
- even https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/ (for this very site, Meta Stack Exchange aka MSE)

You'll need to earn at least 20 reputation on one of the sites in order to participate, but you can poke around now & get a feel for what folks like to talk about.

Comment: Note: not even chat rooms are considered optimal solutions, because people just don't like to fan the fires of the next <put topic here> wars.